# What causes an atom to move to a vacuum?

Tags: vacuum, space

Im in no way an expert in physics but I've been thinking about this for a while.
What force makes something move to a vacuum? 
For example imagine shooting some ice cream into space (lets say it doesnt get burnt up) I'd imagine all the air will get sucked out of it, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest case, consider an open jar of air. The atoms move around randomly, and in fact exchange with atoms from the air around. When the jar is put in the vacuum the atoms that leave are not replaced (well almost never) so the number in the jar drops quickly. This effect is made a lot stronger by the fact that in the air, the atoms trying to leave the jar are hit by incoming atoms and knocked back in (sometimes) but in the vacuum they are almost never knocked back.

The details of a fluid evaporating are complicated by surface tension and so on. But this shows that basic point. In air there are atoms constantly colliding with the object keeping it compact. But in a vacuum these atoms are not there and the object has a greater tendency to expand.

Also, remember that the actual motion due to heat is very high but random. The potential is for the hot atoms at the surface to head off at the thermal velocity. Very rapid.

Comment: To quote Data from star trek TNG - you do not get sucked into space you get blown into space.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, in a vacuum it's not so much a force that causes expansion but rather randomness of particles moving outwards?

Comment: Yes. There is no force pulling into the vacuum, only the particles of the object itself flying outward (to first approximation in a typical situation).

Comment: A related question: if something was so cold that the particles stoped vibrating (0 kelvin) would it theoretically be immune to a vacuum?

Comment: Yes. The rest of this comment is because short comments are not allowed  :p

Answer (score 0):

In classical terms if something starts moving it doesn't need a force to continue moving.

Atoms are made of electrons and nucleons . Nucleons are made of quarks . When quarks and electron are first made , they are created with motion.

This is all very semi-classical mechanics terms because this question seems to can be explained with a semi-classical mechanics instead of quantum mechanics which is the more correct way to do it.

Comment: I dont understand, how is this related to my question?

Comment: As long as the atom doesn't experience any force and is moving , it will keep moving .

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question, I am wondering why the air gets sucked out of food if it were to be put in space. As in, what physically causes the air particles/atoms to be sucked into the vacuum of space

Comment: Due to the lower pressure of the vacuum than the pressure of the food container.